# In Python, how can I increment a count conditionallly?

Tags: python, increment

Say I have the list:

```
list = [a,a,b,b,b]
```

I'm looping over the list. The variable "count" increments by 1 when the previous letter is the same as the current letter. Below is only part of the code:

```
for item in list:
    if item == previous:
        count +=1
return count
```

The example above returns 3, 1 for the repeat a and 2 for the bs. What can I use to make it so count only increases once for each for a total of 2? I tried using a variable "found" that returns True or False depending on whether the letter has been seen before, but this of course doesn't work for something like [a,a,a,c,a,a,a], which returns 1 for the first run of "a"s and not 2, as I want.

Edit: I'm probably making this harder than it needs to be. All I want is for anytime a string is repeated continuously for a count to be incremented by one. [a,b,b,c,a,a,a,a,c,c,c,] should return 3. [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a] should return 1.

Comment: `=` is never an equality operator in python; it is always a binding (aka assignment) operator. the results will be different if the code was `item == previous` .. also, you need to bind something to `previous` for it to make sense.

Comment: don't overwrite the list builtin name with a variable

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?  If you want to count the number of characters that are the same as the previous character then you DO want the answer 3 for "aabbb".  But then you say you want the answer 2 for "aaacaaa" which I would think would be 4.  What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: since you want `a,a,b,b,b` to be 2 and not 3, and you also want `a,a,a,c,a,a,a` to give two, I think you're trying to count distinct contiguous groups of equal elements of length >= 2.  If so, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> seq1 = ['a','a','b','b','b']
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(seq1)]
[('a', ['a', 'a']), ('b', ['b', 'b', 'b'])]
>>> seq2 = ['a','a','a','c','a','a','a']
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(seq2)]
[('a', ['a', 'a', 'a']), ('c', ['c']), ('a', ['a', 'a', 'a'])]
```

and thus

```
>>> sum(len(list(g)) >= 2 for k,g in itertools.groupby(seq1))
2
>>> sum(len(list(g)) >= 2 for k,g in itertools.groupby(seq2))
2
```

but this is just a guess.  It's the only thing I can think of which matches the only two data points you've given, at least assuming that I'm interpreting "1 for the first run of "a"s and not 2, as I want" correctly.  That leaves it unclear whether you want the total to be 2 or the contribution from the first run of "a" to be 2.

Comment: you can use `sum(1 for i in g)` as a memory efficient version of `len(list(g))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def max_contiguous_repeat(data):
   max_repeats = 0
   if data:
      previous = data[0]
      count = 0
      for item in data[1:]:
         if item == previous:
            count += 1
            continue
         max_repeats = max(count, max_repeats)
         previous = item
         count = 0
      max_repeats = max(count, max_repeats)
   return max_repeats
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
previo = None
counter = 0
temp_l, checked = [], []
for item in a:
    if item != previo:
        temp_l = []

    if not temp_l or item == previo:
        temp_l.append(item)
        previo = item

    if len(temp_l) >= 2 and item not in checked:
        counter += 1
        checked.append(item)

    previo = item

print counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want this to produce, but either way, your code is missing a lot.

```
my_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
previous = None
count = 1
for item in my_list:
    if item == previous:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 1
    previous = item
print count
```

- First, `a` and `b` are variables.... `'a'` and `'b'` are strings.
- Next, you never initialized `previous` and `count`.
- Next, you were using `=` (which is assignment) instead of `==` for comparison.
- Next, you weren't resetting `count` if the two were not equal.
- Finally, you weren't setting `previous` to `item` each iteration.

This code produces `3`, because there are 3 b's at the end.

Comment: This code still increments every time item = previous. Also, I don't need count to reinitialize to zero.

Comment: Well then, I really have no idea what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: As I said, that is only part of my code. I'm sure it wouldn't work if I didn't have a and b as strings and initialized previous and count. I know exactly why I get 3, that's just not what I'm trying to do. for the list, for example, ["a","c",b","b","a","a","a"], I'm trying to get 2--one for b and one for a. I don't want an increment for each a or each b, just once for the whole run. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to only count the number of letters that are repeated at least twice in a row in the list?  You could store a list of letters found.  Something like this should accomplish what you need:

```
l = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
repeated = []
previous = None
count = 0
for item in l:
    if item == previous and item not in repeated:
        count += 1
        repeated.append(item)
    else:
        repeated = []
    previous = item
return count
```

Note that DSM has posted a much more python-esque way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
defaultdict=collections.defaultdict
def get_count(string):
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for k in string:
        d[k]+=1
    return max(d.items(),key=lambda a:a[1])
```

Something like this could work, and you can use it like:

```
common_character,occurances=get_count("aaaaabbbbbcccdddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question clearly and it's rather old now but for what it's worth is this what you wanted (the number of unique values)?

```
>>> some_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
>>> len(set(some_list))
2
```

See also https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets.